How does bash <command-argument> work?
About bash
For a new tty when is executed the echo $SHLVL command it displays 1 as expected. Now, if in the same tty is executed the bash command and later again the echo $SHLVL command it displays 2. Is mandatory use the exit command to exit of course. Furthermore I did do realize that each bash has its own history command and the user is interacting or has access in the current bash.
So far, after to did do a research it seems it is a kind of subshell (correct me if I am wrong), it because mostly a subshell is created through the (<command>) approach instead.
Just as playing I executed the bash cat /etc/os-release command and nothing is printed.
Therefore being curious
Question

How does bash <command-argument> work?

As extra question:

Under what circumstances the bash <command-argument> approach would be mandatory to be applied?

Observation
In the answer was indicated to expect an error message. Well, the error mentioned is correct (tested on Ubuntu and Fedora) but in my case the bash cat /etc/os-release command was applied as an argument to create a docker container based on Linux and none error was shown as indicated from the beginning and it was the reason to create this post. Well it is other history

What exactly is your question? Are you asking about the command arguments bash takes, or what a subshell is? What has $SHLVL to do with it?

Somewhat related: Difference between "bash executable" and "bash -c executable"

bash <command-argument> is described in the manual section on invoking Bash:

If arguments remain after option processing, and neither the -c nor the -s option has been supplied, the first argument is assumed to be the name of a file containing shell commands (see Shell Scripts).

So
bash cat /etc/os-release

looks for a file named cat containing shell commands (in other words, a shell script). Typically, you should have seen an error along the lines of
/usr/bin/cat: /usr/bin/cat: cannot execute binary file

unless you happen to have a file named cat in the current directory, in which case Bash would try to run that instead.
I can’t think of a context where using bash <command-argument> would be mandatory, but it can be useful in a variety of circumstances, for example:

run a text file as a shell script without making it executable;
run a shell script with different shell options (for example, bash -x script).

This is the mechanism used when executing scripts through a shebang: a script starting with #! /bin/bash ends up run as /bin/bash <path-to-the-script>. So running a script requiring bash directly or using bash <path-to-the-script> is equivalent. (But see Why the "-" in the "#! /bin/sh -" shebang? for useful shebang information.)

Thanks. Has a lot of sense about the scripts files scenario. (A) I am assuming it is executed within the subshell, right? (B) Is it the same as the ./script.sh approach?. If both are the same the unique difference is that the former lets apply some options (as shown in your link provided) prior the execution.  I know source as . script.sh is executed within the same bash and it is other history.

(A) The script is executed by the new shell (which isn’t necessarily a subshell — consider scenarios where a different shell is involved, for example if your current shell is zsh but you run bash). (B) Assuming ./script.sh has a shebang line invoking bash, then yes, it’s she same.

Huge thanks for the extra feedback. So (C)  Linux would execute the "bash" twice right? one from the command itself "bash script.sh" and the other from the shebang (/bin/sh which it is a link to either /bin/dash or /bin/bash) from the script. Is it correct?

No, if you run bash <path-to-script>, bash is only run once.
